How to fix revert problem in universal router?
I want to sell token using universal router in base network but transaction revert is coming every time. Can anyone solve this?
CODE
const { BigNumber } = require('bignumber.js');
const routerAbi = require('./abis/routerAbi.json');
const erc20Abi = require('./abis/erc20Abi.json');
require('dotenv').config();

const tokenAddress = '0x717d31A60a9e811469673429c9F8Ea24358990f1';
const routerAddress = '0x3fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad';
const pairAddress = '0xb65d78c4d8b987c8c05c85544786a6dd7f6c3421';
const yourWalletAddress = '0xBa1347eAB403FAEd265E906634a6D5962D1E68DD';
const privateKey = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;
const rpcUrl = 'https://mainnet.base.org';

const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(rpcUrl));
const routerContract = new web3.eth.Contract(routerAbi, routerAddress);
const tokenContract = new web3.eth.Contract(erc20Abi, tokenAddress);

const amountToSell = new BigNumber(10).times(new BigNumber(10).pow(18)); // 10 tokens with 18 decimals
const deadline = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 20; // 20 minutes from now
const slippageTolerancePercentage = 2; // 2% slippage tolerance
const liquidityPoolFee = 100; // 1% liquidity pool fee

// Approve Router to spend tokens
async function approveToken() {
    const approvalData = tokenContract.methods.approve(routerAddress, amountToSell.toFixed()).encodeABI();
    const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(yourWalletAddress);
    const approvalTxObject = {
        from: yourWalletAddress,
        to: tokenAddress,
        gas: 400000,
        data: approvalData,
        nonce: nonce
    };
    const signedTx = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(approvalTxObject, privateKey);
    const approvalTxReceipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction);
    //console.log('Approval transaction receipt:', approvalTxReceipt);
}

// Sell tokens for ETH
async function sellTokensForEth() {
    await approveToken(); // Approve token transfer first

    const commands = '0x3593564c'; // MethodID for execute function
    const inputs = [
        web3.eth.abi.encodeParameter('bytes[]', []), // Empty array for commands
        web3.eth.abi.encodeParameter('address', tokenAddress), // Token address
        web3.eth.abi.encodeParameter('uint256', amountToSell.toFixed()), // Amount of tokens to sell
        web3.eth.abi.encodeParameter('address', pairAddress), // Pair address
        web3.eth.abi.encodeParameter('uint256', 0), // Minimum amount of ETH to receive
        web3.eth.abi.encodeParameter('uint256', deadline), // Deadline
        web3.eth.abi.encodeParameter('uint24', liquidityPoolFee), // Liquidity pool fee (1%)
        web3.utils.toWei((slippageTolerancePercentage / 100).toString(), 'ether') // Slippage tolerance (2%)
    ];

    const data = web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall({
        name: 'execute',
        type: 'function',
        inputs: [
            { type: 'bytes', name: 'commands' },
            { type: 'bytes[]', name: 'inputs' },
            { type: 'uint256', name: 'deadline' }
        ]
    }, [commands, inputs, deadline]);

    const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(yourWalletAddress);
    const txObject = {
        from: yourWalletAddress,
        to: routerAddress,
        gas: 400000,
        data: data,
        nonce: nonce
    };
    const signedTx = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(txObject, privateKey);
    const txReceipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction);
    console.log('Swap transaction receipt:', txReceipt);
}

sellTokensForEth();

ERROR
        var error = new Error(message);
                    ^

Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:
{
  "blockHash": "0x40b4f01ff8e9e2e1ab974cae15125c15fdedb732744bd7bb97878c13a3d52f84",
  "blockNumber": 13249165,
  "contractAddress": null,
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 4941915,
  "effectiveGasPrice": "0x56883d0",
  "from": "0xba1347eab403faed265e906634a6d5962d1e68dd",
  "gasUsed": 31847,
  "l1Fee": "0x23cdb8bb90",
  "l1GasPrice": "0x4c4a924aa",
  "l1GasUsed": "0x1aa4",
  "logs": [],
  "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "status": false,
  "to": "0x3fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad",
  "transactionHash": "0x1f31312e9fd952fa17f998eec65ee20c95cbfa1de7e34be76ea8683b51deba9a",
  "transactionIndex": 36,
  "type": "0x0"
}
    at Object.TransactionError (d:\uniswapV3-base-mainnet-\node_modules\web3-core-helpers\lib\errors.js:87:21)
    at Object.TransactionRevertedWithoutReasonError (d:\uniswapV3-base-mainnet-\node_modules\web3-core-helpers\lib\errors.js:98:21)
    at d:\uniswapV3-base-mainnet-\node_modules\web3-core-method\lib\index.js:393:57
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  receipt: {
    blockHash: '0x40b4f01ff8e9e2e1ab974cae15125c15fdedb732744bd7bb97878c13a3d52f84',
    blockNumber: 13249165,
    contractAddress: null,
    cumulativeGasUsed: 4941915,
    effectiveGasPrice: '0x56883d0',
    from: '0xba1347eab403faed265e906634a6d5962d1e68dd',
    gasUsed: 31847,
    l1Fee: '0x23cdb8bb90',
    l1GasPrice: '0x4c4a924aa',
    l1GasUsed: '0x1aa4',
    logs: [],
    logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    status: false,
    to: '0x3fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad',
    transactionHash: '0x1f31312e9fd952fa17f998eec65ee20c95cbfa1de7e34be76ea8683b51deba9a',
    transactionIndex: 36,
    type: '0x0'
  }
}

Node.js v20.11.1```


Yours is reverting right at the start, it isn't getting anywhere so there could be lots of things wrong with it. I detail calling the universal router in one answer and troubleshooting in another. You should be able to get it from these: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/162201/layer2-revert-execution-error-when-calling-exactinputsingle-in-uniswap-v3/162272#162272 |  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78324700/warning-error-encountered-during-contract-execution-execution-reverted-base
